# Does $f'(x) = f(x-1)$ have a solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm more concerned with the general question of whether any function satisfies the differential equation $f'(x) = f(x+a)$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I've tried solving it myself, to no avail.

Comment: This is a simple type of [Delay Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). It's possible to find non-zero solutions by trying solutions of the form $e^{\lambda x}$. Finding $\lambda$ involves the Lambert W function.

Comment: Thank you so much!